# How would a question about recreating a game in another game be tagged?

Tags: discussion, tags, allowed-questions, site-policies

Recently I have been trying to recreate a video game in another video game. I am planning on asking a question here, however I’m not sure exactly how I should tag this question. With both games? With the game I’m recreating in only? I’m at a loss.

Comment: What video game are you trying to recreate in another video game? And in what manner? The answer will depend on what exactly are you trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure it would *necessarily* be off-topic. Depends heavily on the question.

If you are stuck on one specific problem (example; using commands in Minecraft to do X when Y occurs), then that would likely be on topic. In which case I would only tag it with the appropriate Minecraft tags. You can explain in the body of the question that you are trying to get it to behave like [example from other game] for context, but I don't think tagging that game would be appropriate.

The question may become off-topic if you are asking how to go about the project overall, or too many different different questions in one (too broad).

Comment: When the OP said "recreate," I assumed they meant developing a game, hence my response.

Comment: @TimmyJim no, would not be developing a game, as it would only be using existing tools from a game, although maybe that’s considered developing a game because it would be using those tools to create a game.

Comment: @Topcode that would still be off-topic for this site, but definitely sounds more up the alley for the game development SE site.  Our site is generally more for questions relating to _playing video games_ to word it broadly.

Comment: @Topcode What video game are you trying to recreate in another video game (and using which software tool)?

Answer (score 1):

This question would be off-topic for our site. See our [on topic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page.

You should check out the [game development stack exchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) site and see if it would fit in there.